# XML Parser : troubles with Apple XML 

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am using this xml file  :
http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=10/xml

from apple.com/rss and use a classic code to parse it...

First strange thing , when I log that :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

NSLog(@"string : %@",string);

if (!currentElementValue) {
    // init the ad hoc string with the value     
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
} else {
    // append value to the ad hoc string
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];

}
```

}

I get some HTML elements !! But FireFox displays a full XML document when you look at the code of the page !

Then ... when i try to get some information from any tag , I add a lot of whitespace and newline element before the expected value...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
        didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
        qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {



    // Check tag name

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        NSString *trimmedString = [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        [currentElementValue setString:trimmedString];
        NSLog(@" title: %@",currentElementValue);
        [app setAppName:currentElementValue];
    }


    // Check tag
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {

        [apps addObject:app];

        // release user object
        [app release];
        app = nil;

    }


    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;

}
```

Return eg :

> title:

```
                Angry Birds - Clickgamer.com
```

I've already used that parser class with others XML files and it worked, but now with Apple XML file it doesn't ... why ?

Comment: You need to post more of your implementations of `parser:foundCharacters:` and `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:`.  Which HTML elements did you find in `parser:foundCharacters:`?  You should realize we're not psychics who can magically read your code on your Mac!

Comment: yes, sorry. I edited the code.

Comment: HTML elements were the same of the code source of the XML file but with Safari...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean by "the same with the source of XML but with Safari"?

Comment: That a little wired... If you look at the source code of the xml in FireFox, you see the entire XML file (and just XML tag). BUT if you do the same with Safari, you will see ONLY html tag... you can test by yourself. And that's why I am surprised to get some of this HTML tag...

Comment: I can't even see that URL in Safari. It's an RSS feed and I'm sent to an RSS reader. ???

Comment: I know.... but i don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a lot of whitespace before the desired content because of the way the XML is constructed, you can trim it before you use it,

```
   ....
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    NSString * trimmedString = [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@" title: %@",trimmedString);
    [app setAppName:trimmedString];
}
   ....
```

---

As for your question about `parser:foundCharacters:`, [`the documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3afoundCharacters%3a) states this,

> Sent by a parser object to provide its
>   delegate with a string representing
>   all or part of the characters of the
>   current element.

So you shouldn't expect it to print the entire XML. It will give you bits and pieces of it.